# Listing items in Combobox

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I am trying to create a TitleAreaDialog in JFace. I have a text field where a username is entered and a combobox for selecting the group of the user. The requirement is that, when I type a username in the first text field, my combobox should show only the groups corresponding to that username (There is a table in database where each username is assigned a set of groups). So I have written the code for retrieving the groups corresponding to the username entered. But I am not getting the list of groups in the combobox.

Should I add any listeners to the textbox or combobox so that once I type the username in the textfield, I will get the list of groups corresponding to that username in the combobox?

Kindly help me as I am very new to this topic and Java as well.

```
text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
text.setBounds(205, 10, 109, 19);

Combo combo = new Combo(composite, SWT.NONE);
combo.setBounds(205, 49, 109, 21);

String reponame=text.getText();
String[] grpNames=db.getcomboValues(reponame);
combo.setItems(grpNames);
```

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `ModifyListener` to your text widget and re-populate the combo box on every change like so:

```
text.addListener( SWT.Modify, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    String reponame = text.getText();
    String[] grpNames = db.getcomboValues( reponame );
    combo.setItems( grpNames );      
  }
} );
```

This will however cause a database request whenever the text changes. Depending on how long your query takes, this may render your UI unusable.